# NSUserDefaults between app delegate and view controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, nsuserdefaults, appdelegate

if im using

```
settings = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
```

in my view controller, will using

```
settings = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
```

in my app delegate (2 different properties in 2 different files) have this

```
[settings objectForKey:@"location"];
```

return the same value? Thanks.

Comment: Read the documentation of NSUserDefaults, then google "singleton pattern".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YES. That is the purpose of standardUserDefaults.

Comment: thanks. thats what i thought, but i just wanted to check. ill accept your answer once they let me